# How to bring a CMD.EXE window to top

Tags: cmd

How to bring CMD.EXE window to top? (I would prefer a command or script without a need to compile anything).

Comment: Will a Windows shortcut work?

Comment: If I can execute it within the script for the script window - sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wscript.Shell object accessible from Windows Script Host (either VBS or JS) has a method called "AppActivate" which, when passed a window title, will attempt to "activate" (which may bring it to the foreground if it's not minimised).

The following code snippet in VBScript worked on my machine:

```
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.AppActivate "Command Prompt"
```

(Edited: Initially I hadn't tried it. Then I did)

Comment: This is perfect.  Saved this as a file named top.vbs, and I am calling it from within my batch file with  `start "" "\\server\share\top.vbs"`  Thanks!

Comment: @skotte Jesus F. Christ, start "<sum friggin name>" ... / ....AppActivate("<dat friggin name>")   so it can handle more than one friggin cmd window ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With compiling:

Easy, just use Win32 API to FindWindow according to its title or class and then send it a message or bring it to the front.

Without compiling:

I'd suggest you'd find a command line utility that can do the equivalent of FindWindow and SetForgroundWindow, so you could call it from a batch file or any other script.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AutoHotkey Script:

```
^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , Ahere
Return
```

Save it as a .ahk file. Run it after you've installed Autohotkey. Now click the window of your choice and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and the window should be always on top

Comment: for whatever reason this does not work with CMD if you run it in admin mode